# Creating a Relationship in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4J (and to databases in general).  I've read the book "Learning Neo4J", and I have no problems creating nodes.  I have big problems creating relationships.  The nodes represent countries (just two), and also cities (eight).

Here are my `CREATE` statements for creating the country nodes:

```
CREATE(SG: Country {Name:'Singapore', FullName:'Republic of
   Singapore'})
CREATE(MY: Country {Name:'Malaysia',
   FullName:'Malaysia'})
```

The following are my CREATE statements for creating cities:

```
CREATE(City1: City {Name:'Singapore'})
CREATE(City2: City {Name:'Kuala Lumpur'})
CREATE(City3: City {Name:'Johor Bahru'})
CREATE(City4: City {Name:'Malacca'})
CREATE(City5: City {Name:'Georgetown'})
CREATE(City6: City {Name:'Alor Star'})
CREATE(City7: City {Name:'Klang'})
CREATE(City8: City {Name:'Shah Alam'})
```

So far so good.  But when I issue these commands to create relationships, they don't work:

```
CREATE(City1)-[:CITY_IN]->(SG)
CREATE(City2)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City3)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City4)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City5)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City6)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City7)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City8)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Sincerly,
CKLee

Comment: It's worth reading through the Neo4j developer's manual. The key thing to keep in mind regarding this particular issue is that variables you use to bind to your graph elements (SG, MY, City1, City2, etc) only exist for the duration of a query, and even then can go out of scope due to WITH clauses if not explicitly included in the WITH. They are never saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you ran these three blocks of cypher separately, in the browser/shell?

If so, you've lost what the identifiers represent. This will work if you run it as one transaction-

```
CREATE(SG: Country {Name:'Singapore', FullName:'Republic of
   Singapore'})
CREATE(MY: Country {Name:'Malaysia',
   FullName:'Malaysia'})
CREATE(City1: City {Name:'Singapore'})
CREATE(City2: City {Name:'Kuala Lumpur'})
CREATE(City3: City {Name:'Johor Bahru'})
CREATE(City4: City {Name:'Malacca'})
CREATE(City5: City {Name:'Georgetown'})
CREATE(City6: City {Name:'Alor Star'})
CREATE(City7: City {Name:'Klang'})
CREATE(City8: City {Name:'Shah Alam'})
CREATE(City1)-[:CITY_IN]->(SG)
CREATE(City2)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City3)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City4)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City5)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City6)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City7)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
CREATE(City8)-[:CITY_IN]->(MY)
```